# How can I set a variable with twig?

Tags: symfony, variables, foreach, datatables, twig

I want to set the variable `key` before using it

```
  "columns": [
      {% for key, value in columns %}
        {"data": "{{ key }}"},
        {% endfor %}
      { "data": "id" }
    ]
```

My approach:

```
  "columns": [
      {% for key, value in columns %}
      {% set result = '{{ key }}' %}
        {"data": "{{ result }}"},
        {% endfor %}
      { "data": "id" }
    ]
```

But it is not working. I get the error message:

> Requested unknown parameter '{{ key }}'

Comment: just an aside ... why is it needed? You've added 1 new line, and attempted to set key to a name with 3 more chars... and then echo it straight away .. why not just stick with key? - also just do `{% set result = key %}`

Comment: @treyBake Because I want to use an if statement later

Comment: you can still use key in an if statement, there's no point setting a var inside a loop to use for a conditional outside of the loop - it will be set to the last iteration of the loop ... so it won't ever be an accurate conditional. And if you are wanting the last iteration, then just call the last iteration and do the if on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{% set result = key %}
```

From what I see, you want to set the value of `result` variable, result of `key` is already set, you just didn't access it correctly.

Comment: One question, what if I want the variable to be `{{ key }}.name`, because I tested `{% set result = key.name %}` and this did not work out

Comment: From your code, `key` is just an integer or a string (not an object like you're suggesting) that represents each key from indexed `columns` array. Perhaps you're looking for `value` ? Try `{% set result = value %}` . Because I have no clue what `key.name` should be, I'm afraid I cannot help you more than this. Perhaps after you set `{% set result = value %}`, you can get to `value.name`.

Comment: Thank you very much